# Combining left and right text justification in a legend in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, plot, graph, legend

I would like to have my legend look like this in Matlab

> [Category1     1.5%]
>
> [Category2     2.3%]

Where the text is left-adjusted and the percentages are right-adjusted.
Is there a way of doing this? I was thinking of adding a second text object to each entry in the legend, but I cannot figure a way of doing this. The existing legend text objects have the legend itself as a parent, however, I cannot add new text objects to it. Even trying to copy a text object by value does not work:

```
[l_h, object_h] = legend({'A', 'B'});
text_h = findobj(object_h,'Type','Text');

copyobj(text_h(1), text_h(1).Parent)
```

gives me

> Error using copyobj
>
> Text cannot be a child of Legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, by playing around, I found a way to do this.
You can't create a new Text object under the legend object, however, there is another Transform object that holds the legend markers that can be used for the same purpose. Not sure what is the logic but this works:

```
[l_h, object_h] = legend({'A', 'B'});
text_h = findobj(object_h,'Type','Text');
marker_h=findobj(object_h,'Type','Patch');
legend_parent_h = marker_h(1).Parent;

p_h = copyobj(text_h(i), legend_parent_h);    

% now anything can be done with p_h
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick with `sprintf` and use a font which has constant spacing for each character, e.g. courier:

```
% demo from legend help:
x = 0:.2:12;
plot(x,besselj(1,x),x,besselj(2,x),x,besselj(3,x));
% 3 legend entries which will have "TXT NUMBER%" format
text = {'First 10%','Second 20%','Third 30%'};
% make a copy of the text
numbers = text;

% split the text and numbers into two cell arrays
%    You probably have them split before here in your
%    code - I just do it here for demo.
for ii=1:length(text)
  entries = strsplit ( text{ii} );
  text{ii} = entries{1};
  numbers{ii} = entries{2};
end

% find the longest text entry.
mlen = max(cellfun ( @length, text ));

% create your format string - left justify the text.
formatstr = sprintf ( '%%-%is %%s', mlen );

% update the text which will go in the legend
for ii=1:length(text)
  text{ii} = sprintf ( formatstr, text{ii}, numbers{ii} );
end

% create the legend 
h = legend ( text );
% Change the font name - this is important!!
h.FontName = 'Courier';
```

[image: Above code produces the following image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: this does not work for me unfortunately as I need to use a specific font which is not fixed width.